# What reference is this scene involving riding a bicycle to watch the sunrise making?

Tags: watamote

In *Watamote* episode 2, Tomoko meets Hatsushiba from *Class 1-17* and starts imagining a scene where they are riding a bicycle to watch the sunrise.

What is this scene a reference to?

[image: Mokocchi and her shirt]  [image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a reference to Ghibli Studio's [Whisper of the Heart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisper_of_the_Heart).
The BGM sounds like [Country Roads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_Me_Home,_Country_Roads) which also happens to be the theme song of the film.

[image: Whisper of the Heart - Bike scene] [image: Whisper of the Heart - Bike scene 2]